# Shell: simple way to get all lines before first blank line

Tags: shell, awk

What's the best shell command to output the lines of a file until you encounter the first blank line? For example:

```
output these
lines

but do not output anything after the above blank line
(or the blank line itself)
```

awk? something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^$/,$d' <<EOF
this is text
so is this

but not this
or this
EOF
```

Comment: Probably a little clearer to write this as: `sed -e '/^$/,$d' <file>`. Also, if you happen to have huge files (or a lot of them), it could be an issue that this reads the entire file. Otherwise, nice and short!

Comment: I have added a sed solution to my answer which does not read the entire file.

Comment: I like ephemient's sed -e '/./!Q' solution, too.

Comment: Besides just giving the code, some explanation of how this works would've helped us beginners.

Comment: This is great. I adjusted it to the following to handle a blank line with whitespace: sed -e '/^\s*$/,$d'

Answer (score 7):

More `awk`:

```
awk -v 'RS=\n\n' '1;{exit}'
```

More `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/./p;/./!q'
sed -e '/./!{d;q}'
sed -e '/./!Q'   # thanks to Jefromi
```

How about directly in shell?

```
while read line; do [ -z "$line" ] && break; echo "$line"; done
```

(Or `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo`, if your shell is buggy and always handles escapes.)

Comment: Nice awking! The second sed can be shortened to `'/./!Q'` - `Q` quits immediately, without auto-printing. +1

Comment: I tried some timings: `'/./!Q'` 2.5s; `'/./!{d;q}'` 5.5s; `'/^$/Q'` 7.5s.

Comment: Note that BSD `sed` (which is installed on OSX by default) doesn't appear to support the `q` or `Q` modifiers.

Answer (score 6):

With sed:

```
sed '/^$/Q' <file>
```

Edit: sed is way, way, way faster. See ephemient's answer for the fastest version.

To do this in awk, you could use:

```
awk '{if ($0 == "") exit; else print}' <file>
```

Note that I intentionally wrote this to avoid using regular expressions. I don't know what awk's internal optimizations are like, but I suspect direct string comparison would be faster.

Comment: Note that BSD `sed` (which is installed on OSX by default) doesn't appear to support the `q` or `Q` modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

```
# awk '!NF{exit}1' file
output these
lines
```

Answer (score 3):

Awk solution

```
awk '/^$/{exit} {print} ' <filename>
```

Comment: `1` is shorter  than writing `{print}` and does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Perl:

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    last if length == 1;
    print;
}

__DATA__
output these
lines

but don't output anything after the above blank line
(or the blank line itself)
```

Comment: perl -pe 'exit if m/^$/' (filename)

Comment: Joe, your Perl solution is nice.  I wish I had thought of it.

Comment: @Joe: `m` is redundant, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603389/shell-simple-way-to-get-all-lines-before-first-blank-line/1603576#1603576

Answer (score 1):

#### A couple of Perl one-liners

```
$ perl -pe'last if /^$/' file..

$ perl -lpe'last unless length' file..
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl solution:

```
perl -00 -ne 'print;exit' file
perl -00 -pe 'exit if $. == 2' file
```